# How to avoid ecllipse juno failed to start?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

while starting `Eclipse Juno` frequently, I am getting `server failed to start`..I deleted `.snap` and temp folders also but I am getting same problem frequently.

If I change work space some times it runs some times it is not starting.why it is coming how to avoid that?

Please,clear my problem I am getting it very frequently.

```
console error:
```

```
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sample]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sample]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [DisplayServlet] and [com.sensiple.DisplayServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/DisplayServlet] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sample]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class loader
```

Comment: Your error messages are related to problems with a Tomcat server. Don't see how this could keep Eclipse itself from starting.

Comment: You've solved the duplicate URI mapping shown as a root cause? This would be a combination of the web.xml file and the servlet class itself, if it has Annotations mapping it. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [DisplayServlet] and [com.sensiple.DisplayServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/DisplayServlet] which is not permitted

Comment: ya but i am using only annotation.i removed uri patern in web.xml

Answer (score 1):

You already did the first thing to try, which is to switch to a different workspace.

This is basically impossible to debug.  If I were you, I'd remove your installed version of Eclipse and reinstall the latest version, which is Kepler (4.3.1) now.